# Exclude Everywhere but Admin Area?

Tags: php, admin

Currently I have this:

```
if ( ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) || $query->is_archive() || $query->is_search() ) { ... }
```

I tried `!$query->is_admin()` but this didnt seem to work, is there another way to target everything but the admin area? I'm trying to exclude a category

Comment: What do u mean by `target everything `? What do you want? please be specific and clear

Comment: It looks like the question's title is not in agreement with the *target everything but the admin area* in the question's body.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there's no `is_admin()` method for the `WP_Query` class.

But the interesting part is that PHP will not complain about this:

```
$query->is_admin()
```

where `$query` is an instance of `WP_Query`.

It will just always return false.

This is the reason why ([#src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/2f53c1ada2d0c3a0541c131778c3e64fae4e980c/wp-includes/query.php#L4128-L4143)):

```
/**
 * Make private/protected methods readable for backwards compatibility.
 *
 * @since 4.0.0
 * @access public
 *
 * @param callable $name      Method to call.
 * @param array    $arguments Arguments to pass when calling.
 * @return mixed|false Return value of the callback, false otherwise.
 */
 public function __call( $name, $arguments ) {
        if ( in_array( $name, $this->compat_methods ) ) {
                return call_user_func_array( array( $this, $name ), $arguments );
        }
        return false;
}
```

This is from the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php):

> `__call()` is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context.

The magic `__call` method, kicks in when we call the non-existent method `is_admin()`.

I assume you're hooking into the `pre_get_posts` action.

We can use the `is_admin()` check:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( \WP_Query $query )
{
    // Only on the front-end
    if( is_admin() )
        return;

    // ... your stuff here ...

} );
```

or we could use the `is_admin` public attribute of the `WP_Query` instance:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( \WP_Query $query )
{
    // Only on the front-end
    if( $query->is_admin )
        return;

    // ... your stuff here ...

} );
```

where in fact it's based on the `is_admin()` function, in the `parse_query()` method ([#src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/2f53c1ada2d0c3a0541c131778c3e64fae4e980c/wp-includes/query.php#L1769-L1770)):

```
if ( is_admin() )
    $this->is_admin = true;
```